# Remove observations if string part already occurs in another observation in the same group

Tags: r

I am working with a biological data set with species sampled at different stations and dates. Species names consist of genus and species. If the species is not known, then only the genus is given and instead of species name a "sp." or "indet." is given.

The question is: How do I remove all rows containing "sp." and "indet." in species, if the genus name has already been detected at that station and date with a species name given?

(I prefer a tidyverse solution if possible)

```
station <- c("green", "green","green","green","green","green","green","green","blue","blue","blue","blue")
date <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2008-3-25','2008-3-26','2008-3-26','2008-3-26','2008-3-26','2010-11-1','2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2008-3-25'))
species <- c("x t","x sp.","y c","y sp.","x a","d sp.","x indet.","p indet.","x v","x indet.","l k","y indet.")
action_for_row <- c("keep",
                    "remove, since x occurs in same station and date",
                    "keep",
                    "remove,since y occurs in same station and date",
                    "keep",
                    "keep, since d is not represented at this station and date",
                    "remove, since x occurs in same station and date",
                    "keep, since p is not represented at this station and date",
                    "keep",
                    "remove, since x occurs in same station and date",
                    "keep",
                    "keep, since y is not represented at this station and date")
df <- data.frame(station,date,species,action_for_row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this dplyr solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    genus = gsub(" .*", "", species),
    no_species = grepl("\\b(sp|indet)\\.", species)
  ) %>%
  group_by(station, date, genus) %>%
  filter(!no_species | all(no_species)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-genus, -no_species)
# # A tibble: 7 x 4
#   station date       species  action_for_row                                           
#   <chr>   <date>     <chr>    <chr>                                                    
# 1 green   2010-11-01 x t      keep                                                     
# 2 green   2008-03-25 y c      keep                                                     
# 3 green   2008-03-26 x a      keep                                                     
# 4 green   2008-03-26 d sp.    keep, since d is not represented at this station and date
# 5 blue    2010-11-01 x v      keep                                                     
# 6 blue    2008-03-25 l k      keep                                                     
# 7 blue    2008-03-25 y indet. keep, since y is not represented at this station and date
```

Walk-through:

- I'm assuming that the `species` field is always `"genus <space> species"`, where the species is either "real" or one of `sp.` or `indet.`; the space is important in how I split them, though other patterns can probably be handled as well
- I create two new variables: `genus` (the first portion of `species` combo-field) and `no_species`, meaning it contains one of your "sp|indet" patterns
- I group by station, date, and genus, hoping that that is sufficient grouping
- I keep only those that have a species (i.e., `!no_species`) or where all have no species
- (then some group/column cleanup)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I probably have to produce a more comprehensive example, since there can be more than two observations in each group.

Comment: See my edit, I think this is closer to what you are trying to do.

Comment: It seems to work. However, can not understand why :) Can you explain this sentence in more detail "I keep only those that have a species (i.e., !no_species) or where all have no species"? I understand you keep all FALSE since they dont contain "sp." or "indet." - but how does this work " or where all have no species"*

Comment: I used logic that preserved your `action_for_row` intentions. As on example, *"keep, since d is not represented"*. If we look at that row, then `no_species` is true, which suggests we should drop that row. However, that station/date/genus combination has no other row, so we need to keep it. So we discard the row unless it is the only row in that station/date/genus set of data. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks a lot - amazing :)